Why I cannot define the url as directory structure in API Platform Symfony? Always I'm getting error no route found
I have a CDN that serves different assets like javascript, image or css files. I want to define API Resource relative like that:
If file located in /img/place/something.png the developer have to request the domain.com/api/assets/img/place/something.png or if the developer searchs for a script file it can be search with this url: domain.com/api/assets/scripts/index/navbar/navbar.js or domain.com/api/assets/stylesheet/index.css etc. As you can see the path always change dependent on the directory.
I have a API Resource like this:
#[ApiResource(
    shortName: 'Asset',
    operations: [
        new Get(uriTemplate: '/assets/{filePath}', requirements: ['path' => '.+'])
    ],
    uriVariables: [
        'filePath' => new Link(fromProperty: 'filePath', fromClass: BunnyAsset::class)
    ],
    openapiContext: [
        'summary' => 'Retrieves or stores different mime type files into cdn service',
        'parameters' =>
            [
                [
                    'name' => 'filePath',
                    'in' => 'path',
                    'description' => 'The file path of asset',
                    'schema' => ['type' => 'string']
                ]
            ]
    ],
    input: BunnyAssetInput::class,
    output: BunnyAssetOutput::class,
    provider: BunnyAssetStateProvider::class,
    processor: BunnyAssetStateProcessor::class
)]
class BunnyAsset
{
    private ?string $filePath = null;
    private ?string $fileExtension = null;
    private ?string $content = null;

    public function getId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->filePath;
    }

    public function setFilePath(?string $filePath): static
    {
        $this->filePath = $filePath;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFileExtension(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fileExtension;
    }

    public function setFileExtension(?string $fileExtension): static
    {
        $this->fileExtension = $fileExtension;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(?string $content): static
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }
}

And I want to get this path in provider or processors:
class BunnyAssetStateProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    private BunnyClient $bunnyClient;
    public function __construct(BunnyClient $bunnyClient)
    {
        $this->bunnyClient = $bunnyClient;
    }

    /**
     * @throws AssetNotFoundException
     */
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
       var_dump($operation->getParameters());
        $path = $uriVariables['fileName'].'.'.$uriVariables['fileExtension'];

        return $operation instanceof GetCollection ?
            $this->getCollectionProvider($path, $context)
            :$this->getProvider($path,$context);
    }

    /**
     * @throws AssetNotFoundException
     */
    private function getProvider(string $path, array $context): object|array|null
    {
        $content = $this->bunnyClient->fetch($path);

        if($content)
            return (new BunnyAsset())
                ->setFileName($path)
                ->setContent($content)
                ->setFileExtension(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        throw new AssetNotFoundException("Asset $path not found.");
    }

....... etc.

When I try to request to the localhost:8000/api/assets/text/something.txt
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://localhost:8000/api/assets/text%2Fsomething.txt' \
  -H 'accept: application/ld+json'
Request URL
https://localhost:8000/api/assets/text%2Fsomething.txt

I'm getting error :

{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Error",
  "@type": "hydra:Error",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "No route found for \"GET https://localhost:8000/api/assets/text%2Fsomething.txt\" (from \"https://localhost:8000/api\")",
  "trace": [
    {
      "namespace": "",
      "short_class": "",
      "class": "",
      "type": "",
      "function": "",
      "file": "C:\\Users\\...\\vendor\\symfony\\http-kernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener.php",
      "line": 127,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener",
      "short_class": "RouterListener",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "onKernelRequest",
      "file": "C:\\Users\\...\\vendor\\symfony\\event-dispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener.php",
      "line": 116,
      "args": []
    },

How can I resolve this problem?
